# Load CEF in labelframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, chromium-embedded

How can i put this inside a frame or a labelframe?
Been trying everything and nothing.

i need to put it inside a labelframe or frame in tkinter.

Been trying with this https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py
but cant seem to manage it.

can someone help me?
@Czarek Tomczak can you help?

thanks in advance

```
import ctypes
import platform
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from formularios import tabmain0
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import tkinterweb


# platforms
WINDOWS = platform.system() == 'Windows'
LINUX = platform.system() == 'Linux'
MAC = platform.system() == 'Darwin'

class BrowserFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.browser = None
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

    def get_window_handle(self):
        if MAC:
            from AppKit import NSApp
            import objc
            return objc.pyobjc_id(NSApp.windows()[-1].contentView())
        elif self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        else:
            raise Exception('Could not obtain window handle!')

    def on_configure(self, event):
        if self.browser is None:
            # create the browser and embed it in current frame
            rect = [0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()]
            cef_winfo = cef.WindowInfo()
            win_id = self.get_window_handle()
            cef_winfo.SetAsChild(win_id, rect)
            self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo, url="https://www.google.com/")

            # start the browser handling loop
            self.cef_loop()

        # resize the browser
        if WINDOWS:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                0, 0, event.width, event.height, 0x0002)
        elif LINUX:
            self.browser.SetBounds(0, 0, event.width, event.height)

    def cef_loop(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.cef_loop)


def main():
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1200x600')
    root.title('Test')

    settings = {}
    if MAC:
        settings["external_message_pump"] = True

    cef.Initialize(settings=settings)

    container = ttk.Frame(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
    scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
    scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

    scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)

    stathomelib = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Library", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomelib.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomedoc = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Documentation", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomedoc.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomeTools = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="External Tools", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                               highlightthickness=2)
    stathomeTools.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomekib = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Kibana", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomekib.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomeSDC = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="SDC", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomeSDC.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomeshiny = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Shiny", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                               highlightthickness=2)
    stathomeshiny.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomeSMART = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="SMART", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                               highlightthickness=2)
    stathomeSMART.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=NW, pady=2)

    stathomeVPN = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Open VPN", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomeVPN.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=NW, pady=2)


    BrowserFrame(root).pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    home_browser = LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                              highlightthickness=2)
    home_browser.grid(row=0, column=99, rowspan=99, sticky='ne', pady=2)
    valido_browser = tk.IntVar()
    valido_browser.set(False)

    checkbrowser = tk.Checkbutton(home_browser, fg="blue", selectcolor="red", text="Open in Browser",
                                  variable=valido_browser)
    checkbrowser.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=9, sticky="wn")

    def choose_browser(urlbook):
        if valido_browser.get() == 1:
            webbrowser.open(urlbook)
        else:
            # frm_browser_home.insert(tk.INSERT, urlbook)
            frame = tkinterweb.HtmlFrame(home_browser, messages_enabled=False)
            urlbook = urlbook
            frame.load_website(urlbook)
            frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="wnse", ipadx=330, ipady=120)

    choose_browser("http://www.google.com")

    global varLnkOrder
    varLnkOrder = ""
    varLbook = open("Confs/bookmarks.txt", "r").readlines()
    try:
        for line in varLbook:
            undef = ""
            if ":stathomelib" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomelib
                taman = 43
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomedoc" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomedoc
                taman = 43
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomekib" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomekib
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomeSDC" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomeSDC
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomeshiny" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomeshiny
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomeSMART" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomeSMART
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomeVPN" in line:
                try:
                    url = "https://httpd-openvpn-prd.mobime.dev/active.php"
                    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
                        words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and "UNDEF" in text)
                        if ((words) == "UNDEF"):
                            undef = " (UNDEF Found)"
                    else:
                        undef = " (Down!!!)"
                except Exception as e:
                    undef = " (Down!!!)"

                varLnkOrder = stathomeVPN
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomeTools" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomeTools
                taman = 20
                c = 0
                i = 0

            if len(line) > 1:

                titul, urlbook = line.split('<=>')
                if len(titul) > 1:
                    link1 = Label(varLnkOrder, width=taman, text=titul + str(undef), justify="left", anchor="center",
                                  fg="blue", cursor="draft_large")
                    link1.grid(row=i, column=c, sticky="n", pady=2)
                    link1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, urlbook=urlbook: choose_browser(urlbook.rstrip()))
                    i += 1
                    line == ""

    except Exception as e:
        from main import log_error
        log_error(e, "Bookmark_Builder")

    container.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)




    root.mainloop()
    cef.Shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the link in the question, below is a simplified example to embed the browser inside a tkinter frame:

```py
import ctypes
import platform
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef

# platforms
WINDOWS = platform.system() == 'Windows'
LINUX = platform.system() == 'Linux'
MAC = platform.system() == 'Darwin'

class BrowserFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.browser = None
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

    def get_window_handle(self):
        if MAC:
            from AppKit import NSApp
            import objc
            return objc.pyobjc_id(NSApp.windows()[-1].contentView())
        elif self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        else:
            raise Exception('Could not obtain window handle!')

    def on_configure(self, event):
        if self.browser is None:
            # create the browser and embed it in current frame
            rect = [0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()]
            cef_winfo = cef.WindowInfo()
            win_id = self.get_window_handle()
            cef_winfo.SetAsChild(win_id, rect)
            self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo, url="https://www.google.com/")

            # start the browser handling loop
            self.cef_loop()

        # resize the browser
        if WINDOWS:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                0, 0, event.width, event.height, 0x0002)
        elif LINUX:
            self.browser.SetBounds(0, 0, event.width, event.height)

    def cef_loop(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.cef_loop)


def main():
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1200x600')
    root.title('Test')

    settings = {}
    if MAC:
        settings["external_message_pump"] = True
    cef.Initialize(settings=settings)
    BrowserFrame(root).pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
    cef.Shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks acw1668, it didnt open :(

Comment: It works in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.10 and cefpython3 66.1.

Comment: its strange because when i run, it gives error opening but it dont open or give any error. im using mac: (

Comment: If you look into the source code of the link, there are special work to be done in Mac.  One of them is `winfo_id()` cannot be used in Mac.  Go through the code in the link and make required changes.

Comment: @scll.raz Answer updated with Mac special handling.  Since I don't have a Mac, I cannot verify it.

Comment: your update works fine :), the problem is align it with my code.  updated the code on my question

Comment: It is better to raise another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031645/setting-frames-on-tkinter-with-cef