# Setting frames on tkinter with cef

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, chromium-embedded

Can someone help with this?

I have my page defined with frames but when i run the code it only shows the browser window.

This issue is a continuation from [Load CEF in labelframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013867/load-cef-in-labelframe)

Its basicly a window with links and a browser window on the right

```
import ctypes
import platform
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import tkinterweb

global urlset
urlset="https://www.google.com"

# platforms
WINDOWS = platform.system() == 'Windows'
LINUX = platform.system() == 'Linux'
MAC = platform.system() == 'Darwin'

class BrowserFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.browser = None
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

    def open(self, url):
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.LoadUrl(url)

    # inside BrowserFrame
    def on_configure(self, event):
        if self.browser is None:
            self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo,url=urlset)


    def get_window_handle(self):
        if MAC:
            from AppKit import NSApp
            import objc
            return objc.pyobjc_id(NSApp.windows()[-1].contentView())
        elif self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        else:
            raise Exception('Could not obtain window handle!')

    def on_configure(self, event):
        if self.browser is None:
            # create the browser and embed it in current frame
            rect = [0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()]
            cef_winfo = cef.WindowInfo()
            win_id = self.get_window_handle()
            cef_winfo.SetAsChild(win_id, rect)
            self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo, url=urlset)

            # start the browser handling loop
            self.cef_loop()

        # resize the browser
        if WINDOWS:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                0, 0, event.width, event.height, 0x0002)
        elif LINUX:
            self.browser.SetBounds(0, 0, event.width, event.height)

    def cef_loop(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.cef_loop)


def main():

    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error

    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.title('Test')

    settings = {}
    if MAC:
        settings["external_message_pump"] = True

    cef.Initialize(settings=settings)

    container = ttk.Frame(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
    scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
    scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

    scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)

    stathomelib = tk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Library", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomelib.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NW", pady=2)

    stathomedoc = tk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Documentation", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black",
                             highlightthickness=2)
    stathomedoc.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="NW", pady=2)

    home_browser = tk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
    home_browser.grid(row=0, column=99, rowspan=99, sticky='ne', pady=2)

    valido_browser = tk.IntVar()
    valido_browser.set(False)
    checkbrowser = tk.Checkbutton(home_browser, fg="blue", selectcolor="red", text="Open in Browser",variable=valido_browser)
    checkbrowser.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=9, sticky="wn")


    # specify initial width and height
    browser = BrowserFrame(home_browser, width=1200, height=700)
    browser.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=9, sticky="wn")

    def choose_browser(urlbook):
        if valido_browser.get() == 1:
            webbrowser.open(urlbook)
        else:
            browser.open(urlbook)



    global varLnkOrder
    varLnkOrder = ""
    varLbook = open("Confs/bookmarks.txt", "r").readlines()
    try:
        for line in varLbook:
            undef = ""
            if ":stathomelib" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomelib
                taman = 43
                c = 0
                i = 0

            elif ":stathomedoc" in line:
                varLnkOrder = stathomedoc
                taman = 43
                c = 0
                i = 0



            if len(line) > 1:

                titul, urlbook = line.split('<=>')
                if len(titul) > 1:
                    link1 = tk.Label(varLnkOrder, width=taman, text=titul + str(undef), justify="left", anchor="center",
                                     fg="blue", cursor="draft_large")
                    link1.grid(row=i, column=c, sticky="n", pady=2)
                    link1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, urlbook=urlbook: choose_browser(urlbook.rstrip()))
                    i += 1
                    line == ""

    except Exception as e:
        from main import log_error
        log_error(e, "Bookmark_Builder")

    container.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

bookmarks.txt

> <=>:stathomelib
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrth
>
> <=>:stathomedoc Wiki Teltonika
> Commands<=>https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/FMB_SMS/GPRS_Commands
> Lucene Query Syntax(LogTrail
> Search)<=>http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/
>
> <=>:stathomeTools
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/
> aaaaswefdee<=>ryweryfgertgjhslkrghkjreshjglkjhlksghklrhsklrhklegrthuyug/

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? I think you have way too much code right now.

Comment: sure, updated my code

Comment: I don't see any code that using the embedded CEF browser to load selected URL.  `choose_browser()` will use either external browser (`webbrowser`) or `tkinterweb.HtmlFrame`.

Comment: acw1668 please check again

Answer (score 0):

Note that updating `urlset` will not load the URL in the CEF browser automatically.  You need to create a function in `BrowserFrame` to load an URL:

```py
# inside BrowserFrame
def open(self, url):
    if self.browser:
        self.browser.LoadUrl(url)
```

And you need to load a default URL when creating the CEF browser:

```py
# inside BrowserFrame
def on_configure(self, event):
    if self.browser is None:
        ...
        self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(cef_winfo,
                                             url="https://www.google.com")
    ...
```

Then update `main()` as below:

```py
def main():
    ...
    # specify initial width and height
    browser = BrowserFrame(home_browser, width=1200, height=700)
    browser.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=9, sticky="wn")

    def choose_browser(urlbook):
        if valido_browser.get() == 1:
            webbrowser.open(urlbook)
        else:
            browser.open(urlbook)

    # not necessary to call choose_browser() here
    #choose_browser("http://www.google.com")
    ...
```

---

It is not recommended to import same module like below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

Better use the later only.

Comment: didnt work :( it open but say (RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop).  Updated the issue with your updates

Comment: @scll.raz I have tested my changes and it works.  Also my changes have nothing related to threading, so I don't/wonder why you have such error.

Comment: have you see if i assemble the code right in my example? can you send me your or check if i did it right? thanks

Comment: I just use your updated code (removed unused imports) and it works.  Refer [here](https://pastebin.com/VmW32LhY) for the code.

Comment: tried your example from https://pastebin.com/VmW32LhY, it opens an empty browser window (https://ibb.co/9hRVk0S) strange that it works for you and not me. could it be a mac issue?